# How to get the median of sorted values in a file?

Tags: bash, awk

Let's say my file has sorted numbers and looks like this:

```
1
22
36
45
53
```

I want to be able to get 36.
On the other hand, if file has even number of rows like:

```
1
22
36
45
53
67
```

I would like the average (36+45)/2.

I think I can of course use wc to get the number of lines and work with the lines in the middle. But is there a more elegant way to get the median?

Comment: I have a hard time imagining anything more elegant.

Comment: does this answer your question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13731/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-min-max-median-and-average-of-a-list-of-numbers-in

Comment: You want the average of numbers contained in the file or you want the lines count in a file divided by two?

Comment: python3 -c "import fileinput as FI,statistics as STAT; i = [float(l.rstrip()) for l in FI.input()]; print(STAT.median(i))" did what I was looking for. Thanks @mattb!

Comment: Done. Hope it is clearer now

Answer (score 5):

Use a tool specifically designed for the job, for instance GNU datamash:

```
$ seq 5 | datamash median 1
3
$ seq 6 | datamash median 1
3.5
```

Answer (score 5):

here is an `awk` version, not as elegant as `datamash`

```
$ seq 6 | awk '{a[NR]=$1} END{m=int(NR/2)+1; print (NR%2?a[m]:(a[m-1]+a[m])/2)}'
3.5
```